# Editing the message in a Python email using smtplib

Tags: python, pandas, email, ssl, smtplib

So, I have created this simple program, which checks my research data every hour for nans. It works fine, but i want to improve the email that it sends me, when it finds a nan. At the moment, I can only get it to email me anything that i put inside three speech marks, like this
`message = """Missing data, yo."""`

I want it to email me the datetime and file name when it has a nan. I have tried the following, but it doesnt work:

`message = f"Hello, Cairan. {full_name} has missing data."`

and I have tried this, which doesnt work:

`message = """Missing data """ + full_name`

I dont know what i am doing wrong here - please help. I would also be grateful for any advice on how to change the subject title for the email.

Thanks!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This Python script was written for use on an Amazon EC2 server, with the Eltek GPRS Server running.

This code has a 60 minute loop, which:

1. Copies the data from its original location to a temporary 'checking' directory.
2. Imports the listed CSV files
3. Converts all 'No Data' into nans
4. Looks at the last 12 observations and checks if there is any nans - if there are any it will email an email address about the nans.
5. Loops over all files
6. Loops every hour

"""
# Import packages

import os #os
import fnmatch #fn match
import pandas as pd #pandas
import numpy as np #numpy
import sched #scheduler
import time # time
import smtplib #for email
import ssl #for email
from datetime import datetime #datetime
from termcolor import colored #for colouring text

from shutil import copyfile

# Scheduler           
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

# Email
user = '####@gmail.com' #email username (gmail tested and working)
sender = '####@gmail.com' #sendee email address
password = '####' #email password
port = 465 #port - 465 standard
recieve = '####'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

directory = "C:/EltekGateway/"
individual_files = "K01817-12158.csv", "K01830-12197.csv", "K01830-12200.csv"
files = "C:/EltekGateway/checking/K01817-12158.csv", "C:/EltekGateway/checking/K01830-12197.csv", "C:/EltekGateway/checking/K01830-12200.csv"

for full_name in individual_files:
    checking_dir = directory + "checking/" + full_name
    original_dir = directory + full_name
    copyfile(original_dir, checking_dir)
    print(original_dir, checking_dir)

def do_something(sc):
    now = datetime.now()
    print('<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->')
    print('Checking:' , len(files), 'datafiles.', 'Time now =', now)
    for full_name in files:
        df_tmp= pd.read_csv(full_name, skiprows = 5) # read csv to df_tmp
        df_tmp.rename({'TX Channel': 'date'}, axis=1, inplace=True) # rename cols
        df_tmp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_tmp['date'], errors='raise', dayfirst=True) # create datetime col
        df_tmp = df_tmp.replace('No Data', np.nan) # Eltek 'No Data' to nan
        df_check = df_tmp[-12:]
        df_check = df_check.isnull().values.any()
        # df_check = df_check.isna() # Check last observation to see if there is a nan
        df_check_time = df_tmp.date.iloc[-1] # Store datetime for last obs
        now = datetime.now()
        date_string = df_check_time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S")
        # print(df_check) #checking loop
        if df_check.any() == 0: # Check 
            print(date_string, full_name + colored(' - There is NO missing data','green'))
            # print()
        else:
            print(date_string, full_name + colored(' - There IS missing data', 'red'))
            message = """Missing data, yo."""
            # message = f"Hello, Cairan. {full_name} has missing data."
            with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
                server.login(sender, password)
                server.sendmail(sender, recieve, message)
        # print(df_tmp) #checking loop
        # print(full_name) #checking loop
        # print(df_check_time) #checking loop
    print('<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->')
    s.enter(3600, 1, do_something, (sc,))

def main():
    s.enter(3600, 1, do_something, (s,))
    s.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: try this ` msg.as_string()`

Comment: already tried .as_string() - didnt work

Comment: What's the error message returned by `server.sendmail`?

Comment: "but it doesnt work" is not helpful. Did you get an error? If so, post the full traceback. If you did not get an error, then how could you tell that it "doesnt work"? What happened and how is it different from what you wanted.

Comment: So, when i used .as_string(), the code hangs and the loop doesn't complete - there is no error

Answer (score 1):

Your message is malformed.

You have to write it with proper header and such, like so:

```
message = """\
From: Robot <noreply@domain.com>
To: Persoon <persoon@gmail.com>
Subject: Something Fancy Happened!

Hi Persoon,

Your Thing caused Something Fancy!

Yours,

Robot.
"""
```

If you don't want to build the message manually, take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html

Comment: I was about to write this i.e headers..you beat me to it

Comment: I have implemented the header as you suggest, which works fine, when this is outside the loop, but i want it inside the loop, so that I can include the ```full_name``` in the email. But when i put the whole code you suggest inside the loop - replacing the ```message = """Missing data, yo."""``` in my previous code, the email goes through, but in the email I receive, all of the content is contained within the From: part of the email, with nothing in the subject or body

Comment: @CairanVanRooyen can you edit your question, and add to your question a snippet of the block that begins with `if df_check.any() == 0: # Check ` as you have edited?